# Get Blazor Webassembly component to respond to .net events from project Library

Tags: c#, events, f#, blazor-webassembly

Working in #Blazor Webassembly, I have an added project Library. This Library works in the background to updates a data structure with data. When that happens, I want to push the change to the Razor component and have it do, I think, a StateHasChange. Using a button in the component that calls  StateHasChange works, but is a pull flow. In the simplest way possible, how would I get that to be called in response to a push flow? My current thinking is the library issues a .net event or observable. So the razor component would need to subscribe or observe the library publisher. I have explored the EventCallback in Blazor but I am not sure this is the correct path do to my noviceness with Blazor and events in general. The Library is #fsharp but could be #csharp just the same. The stumbling block is how to get the Blazor component to be a subscriber. The idea of a service has been seen, but I am still not sure if that will allow the push update I am seeking. Any simplest examples or advice?

Comment: Since you're using webassembly, is this project library behind a server or with the client? If it's with the client, then to me it sounds like you might want to use a state management service like https://timewarpengineering.github.io/blazor-state/ I'm not recommending this specifically, it was just the first thing to appear on google.